# Compare dates from different years in mySQL

Tags: mysql, date, comparison

I'm getting a weird return when executing this query :

```
SELECT * FROM rrp
WHERE end > "2012-12-31"
```

nothing is returned, although I have one row on this table which "end" column is greater than `"2012-12-31"`:

**rrp**

```
id_r  |  id__b  |    start    |    end     | quantity
27         29     2012-01-01    2012-05-05      1
31         29     2012-11-01    2013-01-01      1
```

EDIT : `start`and `end`are `date` fields

EDIT : I used wrong database for my tests => wrong result
the issue was coming from Zend_Date when adding a day to a date:

$start = "2012-12-31";
$nStart = new Zend_Date($start, "YYYY-MM-dd");
$end = new Zend_Date($nStart);
$end->addDay(1);

When i echoed $end : `echo $end->get("YYYY-MM-dd");`

it outputs `2013-12-31`

Comment: Is "end" actually a date field? I've known MySQL to do does weird things sometimes when it converts data.

Comment: yes they are, sorry for the imprecision

Comment: There is something your not telling us - because with everything you have written in your question it *should* work - [see this very simple example](http://www.sqlize.com/s4kzK77qFK) setup the same as your question (using just the end column)

Comment: I am really sorry, it seems that the script didn't connect to the right database..

Comment: @JerecTheSith Add that to the original question plz

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most likely an issue with how the dates are formatted

This should help 
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/using-date.html

Comment: As `"2012-12-31"` and `2013-01-01` are formatted the same way and `2013-01-01` is configured as a date field I don't understand this output

Comment: When using date fields like that there are sometimes zeros tacked on at end, which the system assigns, but doesnt show, which causes operators to be off by up to a day in some cases, example: '20041003 23:00:00' is greater than '20041003', because '20041003' is
equivalent to '20041003 00:00:00'.

Answer (score 2):

If `end` is a DATE column, it should work as expected:

```
SELECT
    STR_TO_DATE('2013-01-01', '%Y-%m-%d') < "2012-12-31",
    STR_TO_DATE('2012-05-05', '%Y-%m-%d') < "2012-12-31"
```

... returns `0, 1` in my box.

The only possible flaw I can think of is that your system's default date format is not `%Y-%m-%d`:

```
SELECT @@DATE_FORMAT
```

In that case, you need to specify a format every time:

```
SELECT *
FROM rrp
WHERE end > STR_TO_DATE('2012-12-31', '%Y-%m-%d')
```